# Camera view doesn't match what it is actually pointing at

Tags: animation, camera

https://streamable.com/2xhnkv

Whenever I put my view to the active camera it points in a completely different direction that it clearly isn't pointed in. This is extremely frustrating and I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried deleting the camera, duplicating it, making a new one and more and not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell from the video, but it looks like you have two cameras in your scene. Go into the "Scene" tab and make sure you have the correct one set as the rendering camera.